# How can I get Capslock status in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.6, capslock

Does somebody knows a way to check if Capslock is on using Python 2.6?

EDIT: I've already seen this solution [Python - How to get current keylock status?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13129804/python-how-to-get-current-keylock-status), but it gave me a "string out of range" error. If you know why it would be helpful as well!

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13129804/python-how-to-get-current-keylock-status

Comment: First of all, thank you for the fast comment! I've tried using this but it gave me "string out of range" error. I have just copied it.. Do you know why?

Comment: No, we don't, since we don't know what the output of the command looks like on your system.

Comment: I really don't understand what you mean. I have no output.. Just an error. Are we talking about the same solution using module commands?

Comment: What do you see when you run `xset q` on the command line? If it's something like `xset: command not found`, well there you go.

Comment: I think the long and short of it is that there's not an OS-agnostic solution to what you want. Any solutions either rely on shelling to an external command like `xset` or rely on native API interface modules of some sort or the other.

Comment: Josh - You're right, I got 'is not recognized as an internal or external command'. Can I do something with it? Sorry for not knowing anything about this module.. I didn't really get it.
And I guess that every solution that will work, even with a bit work besides just copying code, can be helpful

Comment: @OrelRegev you would need to install [xset](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/man/man1/xset.1.html). The installation process will vary by operating system, and you haven't told us what OS you are using. Either way, this question sure seems to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13129804/python-how-to-get-current-keylock-status

Answer (score 0):

import commands

CapsLock_status=commands.getoutput('xset q | grep Caps')[21:24]

print "CapsLock status is : %s" %CapsLock_status