# How do you check weather or not capslock is on on pygame

Tags: python, keyboard, pygame

I found certain code in a pygame program, this to be exact:

```
caplock = False
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
       if event.key == pygame.CAPSLOCK:
          capslock = True

    if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
       if event.key == pygame.CAPSLOCK:
          capslock = False
```

when you press "caps lock" while it is off, `capslock` is

```
True
```

and when you press "caps lock" while it is on, `capslock` is

```
False
```

Instead of making `capslock` equal to `False` at the beginning, how can I make it equal to `True` if capslock is already on or `False` if it is already off?

Comment: Pygame can only check if a key is pressed, so you will need to look for an external library

Answer (score 1):

On Linux (tested on Linux Mint 18.1 with Python 3.6) you can use:

```
import subprocess
if subprocess.check_output('xset q | grep LED', shell=True)[65] == 50 :
    capslock = False
if subprocess.check_output('xset q | grep LED', shell=True)[65] == 51 :
    capslock = True
print( "capslock ON is : ", capslock )
```

If it doesn't work, check which values subprocess.check_output() gives you if CapsLock is ON and if CapsLock is OFF. Theoretically it should be 0 and 1, not 50, 51, but on my box it is 50, 51.

You can also take a look at ["Python - How to get current keylock status?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13129804/python-how-to-get-current-keylock-status) for further information.

And YES, I think also you need a keypress event from Pygame to know the status of the keys, so to know it in advance you have to use a method from outside of Pygame.